# Is it possible to prevent players from using hacks on a vanilla server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I host a Vanilla (unmodded) Minecraft server, but often find that people are digging straight towards diamonds or instantly killing players with hacking clients.

Is there a way to prevent people from hacking in a vanilla server, or must I use modifications?

Comment: If you're serious about running a Minecraft server, I'd highly suggest running a Bukkit server and using just a few plugins to make it as close to vanilla as possible.

Comment: There's a _reason_ that anti-cheat plugins require [so much work](https://github.com/Updated-NoCheatPlus/NoCheatPlus/graphs/contributors)… Mojang just isn't going to secure the base game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vanilla server is exactly what it is and has no features to prevent these wallhacks and exploits. Your only tools in vanilla are player bans and kicks after people misbehave, or using the whitelist.

To automatically prevent or even detect these exploits you need to be running a modified server. There are many, many [anti-cheat plugins](http://plugins.bukkit.org/?q=cheat&category=None) for [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/), for example.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely! Lots of vanilla servers use command-block powered anticheat systems.

One I'm using is:
http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/29wkwb/vanilla_anticheat_and_antifly_system/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla does not protect against any hacks except flying. In server.properties, set allow-flight to false. It will kick anyone that is flying after a few seconds. I highly recommend a Bukkit server with a plugin such as NoCheat.

Answer (score 0):

So,the vanilla server doesn't got anticheat modification so i recommend Spigot or Bukkit server and this plugins:
AntiBotUltra,
AntiJoinBot,
NoCheat,
NCP,
AntiBot(Against spam on the server)
AntiProxy

So i hope this plugins will help you :)

Answer (score -4):

Use the NoCheatPlus plugin. I tested a hacking client on a server with NC+ (not to actually hack) It disabled a lot of the hacks, as far as I can see. So try that

Comment: That plugin is for CraftBukkit, which is not the vanilla server.